# Adapter Issue modifying Xamarin.Forms BLE example

Tags: c#, bluetooth, xamarin

I am using the Xamarin.Forms Bluetooth HRM Sample, [here](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/BluetoothHeartRateMonitor).

I am new to Xamarin and to using C# for writing apps. I have a couple of questions. Firstly, I want to create a new page which acts as a "home screen", which displays the received characteristics when the app is connected to a heart rate monitor.

The issue I am having, is that I haven't really understood what adapter is? So when I change the `return new NavigationPage (new DeviceList (Adapter));` reference in `app.cs` in the main PCL, I get issues with passing through the adapter. How do I get to `start_page` (my new page) and be able to use BLE functionality in that page, whilst also then being able to navigate from that, to the DeviceList page?

Portable Class Library

*app.cs*

```
namespace HeartRateMonitor
{
    public class App
    {
        static IAdapter Adapter;

        public static Page GetMainPage ()
        {   
            return new NavigationPage (new DeviceList (Adapter));
        }

        public static void SetAdapter (IAdapter adapter) {
            Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

and *DeviceList*

```
namespace HeartRateMonitor
{   
    public partial class DeviceList : ContentPage
    {   
        IAdapter adapter;
        ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;

        public DeviceList (IAdapter adapter)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice> ();
            listView.ItemsSource = devices;

            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender,     DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    devices.Add (e.Device);
                });
            };

            // Lots of functions to perform various BLE scanning operations, timeouts etc. 

        }).Start();
     }
}
```

Thanks